# Make element height of browser window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get my client's browser height and place it into my css.

Here is my main html:

```
<div class="picture" id="picture1">
    <div class="parallax"><img src="assets/img/header-wrap-bg.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

picture class structure :

```
.picture {
    height: /*(Here i wanna place browser height)*/;
}
```

and this is my event :

```
<body onresize="HeaderResize()">
```

how can i do this ?

Comment: yeap :) thanx ... @haim770

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`vh` viewport-height units](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/):

```
.picture {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Here they all are:

> - `vw`: 1/100th viewport width
> - `vh`: 1/100th viewport height
> - `vmin`: 1/100th of the smallest side
> - `vmax`: 1/100th of the largest side

---

Note that this isn't technically the browser's height, rather it is the viewport's height:

> The viewport is the user's visible area of a web page. The viewport varies with the device, and will be smaller on a mobile phone than on a computer screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To make your element to fit to your fullscreen, use below CSS properties,

```css
.picture {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  margin: auto;
}
```